# Is there a way to create DOM elements on the back end for your frontend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I'm using a NodeJS server with Express and I want to create a new DOM element whenever a user decides to be active and delete them when they aren't. The active user should be global to everyone. Is there also a way to do this using event triggers? Aside from calling a function every 'x' seconds that prints the current status of the activeUsers array I can't think of anything.

Basically I want to be able to do something like this from the backend:

```
$('.left').prepend($('<div/>', {class: 'profTemp'}).append(
$('<img/>', {src: test.active[0].profiler, width: 40, height: 40}),
$('<span/>', {text: " " + test.active[0].userNameData})));
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var user = returnUser();
    var profiler = returnProfiler();

    var live = this.checked;
    var userNameData = {
        userNameData: user,
        active: live,
        profiler: profiler
    };

    $.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify(userNameData),
        url: '/updateUserStatus',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response) {

        }
    });
});
```

Server:

```
app.post('/updateJSON', function(req, res) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(clientJSON);
    var exists = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.clients.length; i++)
    {
      if(obj.clients[i].username == req.body.username)
      {
        obj.clients[i] = req.body;
        exists = true;
        $('.left').prepend($('<div/>', {class: 'profTemp'}).append(
          $('<img/>', {src: test.active[0].profiler, width: 40, height: 40}),
          $('<span/>', {text: " " + test.active[0].userNameData})));
      }
    }

    if(exists == false){
      obj.clients.push(req.body);
    }

    clientJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
});
```

Comment: You can use websockets to communicate front and backend end via socket, than the backend can 'broadcast' messages to the front. But who creates the DOM node is the frontend layer. If you are using Nodejs, you can use SOcketIO (https://socket.io/), it's a library for real-time communication in web applications.

Comment: There is no DOM in back end (unless you use a headless browser) and you can only send string data to front end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things need clarification here.

First of all, you cannot create DOM elements on the backend and send them to the frontend. You can create HTML on the backend and send it to the frontend, and then create DOM elements from that HTML on the frontend. Or you can create DOM elements on the backend and then serialize them to HTML, send them to the frontend and then create DOM elements on the frontend from that.

Of course you could in theory expose the client-side DOM to the backend via some real-time API like WebSocket, long-polling AJAX, Socket.io etc. but this would be more complicated than it may appear.

Things like that are usually done with a real-time API that sends messages to the client from the server, will all needed data serialized as JSON, and then the client builds a given DOM tree from that and appends that whenever it needs.

You can use some real-time frameworks like ActionHero to simplify that process:

- https://www.actionherojs.com/

For building the DOM you can use frontend frameworks like Angular, React, Ember, Aurelia, etc.

Comment: Ah right thanks for clearing that upI I also have the list of activeUsers saved as JSON and that is accessible from the frontend and I have a function that polls that. I don't suppose there are event triggers I can have on the object if any data has changed so I can append and remove whatever I need to?